# Searching a two dimensional array in JQuery

Tags: jquery

In JQuery I have a variable declared as a two dimensional array. In my example the first dimension of the array has 4 elements:

```
length: 4
[0]: {...}
[1]: {...}
[2]: {...}
[3]: {...}
```

Each of the 4 elements contains a unique key and a value, like for example:

```
Key: "Some key"
Value: "This is some value"
```

What I would like to do, is search the array, and get the Value where key equals for example "Some key". Can this be done elegantly in a line or two with JQuery?

Comment: Note that if the elements have keys like `Key` and `Value`, it sounds like they're *objects*, not arrays, and so what you have is an array of objects, not a two-dimensional array. (JavaScript doesn't really have two-dimensional arrays anyway, but...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
$.each(theArray, function(index, entry) {
    // Use entry.Key and/or entry.Value here
});
```

Or without jQuery on any modern browser:

```
theArray.forEach(function(entry) {
    // Use entry.Key and/or entry.Value here
});
```

(`forEach` can be shimmed on IE8 and such.)

If you want to stop at the first match, then:

```
$.each(theArray, function(index, entry) {
    if (/* Use entry.Key and/or entry.Value here*/) {
        return false; // Ends the "loop"
    }
});
```

Or without jQuery on any modern browser:

```
theArray.some(function(entry) {
    if (/* Use entry.Key and/or entry.Value here*/) {
        return true; // Ends the "loop"
    }
});
```

or

```
theArray.every(function(entry) {
    if (/* Use entry.Key and/or entry.Value here*/) {
        return false; // Ends the "loop"
    }
});
```

(`some` and `every` can be shimmed on IE8 and such.)